# Communication between Python<->Cython<->C in multithreaded environment

Tags: python, c, multithreading, openmp, cython

First here is the setting of the problem

```
+-------------+                                                 

   Python        P0                    P1    P1                 
                 +                     ^ +   ^ +                
+------------+   |                     | |   | |                
                 |                     + v   + v                
   Cython        +->C0                 C1    C1                 
                      +                ^ +   ^ +                
+------------+        |                | |   | |                
                      |           +----------+-v-----+          
   C                  +->F0... +--+    | |           +------>...
                                  +----+-v-----------+          
+------------+
```

The entry point of the program is a Python function P0 which is calling a C function F0 (from a user library) through Cython. This C function is creating multiple threads using OpenMP. Each thread is using a callback in cython to call the python function P1 to be run in parallel. These P1 functions return a single value to be thrown back into the C code. The problem is: how to call P1 properly using the cython callback with inner C multithread.

I am now well aware of the GIL in Python, and the with/nogil from Cython:
http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#acquiring-and-releasing-the-gil

And also from the API:
https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#non-python-created-threads

The post I read here are only one-sided communication Python->Cython or Cython->Python or the issue of multithreading in C calling Cython omited.

Therefore, how to handle that case ?

Since Cython is used, the API for C is discarded. The most probable solution is related to the with gil/nogil option in Cython.

My idea is that nogil should be put on C0 since the code goes into C library, and with gil on C1.

```
C0(...) nogil
C1(...) with gil
```

Back in the diagram

```
+-------------+                                                 

   Python        P0                    P1    P1                 
                 +                     ^ +   ^ +                
+------------+   |                     | |   | |                
                 |                     + v   + v                
   Cython        +->(C0) nogil        (C1    C1) with gil        
                      +                ^ +   ^ +                
+------------+        |                | |   | |                
                      |           +----------+-v-----+          
   C                  +->F0... +--+    | |           +------>...
                                  +----+-v-----------+          
+------------+
```

However, my experience is that one of the P1 function never returns to the Cython properly and the code remains stuck waiting indefinitely for P1 to return.

What would be the right answer or the explanation to the code being stuck when returning from P1 ?

**ADD1:** The code is a test example working perfectly with one thread (or with OpenMP set to one thread). Also the multithread test is working when not using Python/Cython interface, purely a C/C++ example. Hence the problem related to the GIL or related to threading in Python/Cython.

Comment: Can you put the OpenMP code in Cython? I'm asking because Cython has [OpenMP support](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/parallelism.html) and does (probably) already initialize the threads such that you can use them in Python without further initialization.

Comment: No it is not possible since it is a legacy library. including OpenMP in Cython would mean rewriting a huge part if not all the library.
My question is related to that case specifically. To know if it possible or not. Because no answer was clear about it. I may have a solution but it does not answer the issue stated. I will post it later on when fully tested and if no one can successfully answer.

Answer (score 2):

After examining the generated source, it seems that the declarations

```
C0(...) nogil
C1(...) with gil
```

differ in a subtle way. Namely, `C1() with gil` will *definitely* acquire the GIL when it is called, whereas `C0() nogil` *allows it* to be wrapped in a `with nogil:` context without generating a Cython compilation error. However, unless you explicitly add this context, Cython will generally go ahead and acquire the GIL before entering `C0()`. This results in a deadlock: `C1` waits to acquire a lock which is held by its enclosing function `C0`, but the lock will not be released until `C0` returns. Try replacing calls to `C0()` with `with nogil: C0()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone else can tell you exactly how to do it, but for problems of this type I find it is often good to break things up into simpler pieces. Work out a way to call from Python to Cython to C with a callback and then invoke that callback out to Cython and Python. Do this with a simple test program and then once you have that down, bring in OpenMP and then apply your techniques to the real libraries you are working with.

Also, if you get stuck, maybe you can work around the problem by moving the callback to the Cython or C layer, passing in enough parameters for it to do its job. This might not be possible, depending on your application, but it might allow you to make progress. And it might even perform better. If you are using OpenMP, then performance is clearly important, and removing the language crossing code from the callback invocation means less work at the thread level, which should improve performance.

Comment: In fact it has already been experimented in single thread mode or multithread without interface. I added the information in my post as addendum.

Comment: I am using OpenMP because I am calling in parallel different legacy C codes which are expensive to compute through Python. They are much more costly than the Python layer.